# Members that are only accessible to child class if child class override them?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a base class that has variables that must be overridden if they're going to be used by the child class, but if they're not overridden they can not be accessed by the child class.

Is that possible?

Comment: You can do this with methods using `abstract`. Can also be done with properties. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-define-abstract-properties

Comment: I think the closest thing to what you're looking for is `protected`, but that makes it visible to the subclass.

Comment: abstract is the one I was looking for i think, thank you

Comment: `abstract` does not achieve "but if they're not overridden they can not be accessed by the child class". Nothing will. You can't do what you're asking for.

Comment: I'm in agreement with @Enigmativity, how can something _must_ be overridden, but also _might not_ be overridden. You've got `abstract` for "it must be overridden", and `virtual` for "it can be overridden". What are you actually after?

Comment: Also, for something to be defined in a superclass for a subclass to choose to use means that the superclass can't be used in place of the subclass. This would break the idea of inheritance.

Comment: On further thinking, the feature you're after is the default behaviour of C# when you don't define anything the superclass. All you need to do is define the "variables" in the subclasses as you see fit. That gives you the behaviour that you're looking for.

Comment: Do you want *two* base types? eg `abstract class Base{} abstract class Base2: Base { abstract .... }`. So a child class can extend either the type with this feature, or the type without this feature?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman - That's a good way to look at this. I'd write it up as an answer if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

No, nothing like that exists in the language, at least with all the requirements you're looking for.

This explanation also assumes that "child class" is not abstract.

> ...a base class that has variables that must be overridden...

That's what [`abstract`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract) is for. This keyword means you *must* override the member in a child class. You must also ensure that your base class is `abstract` as well (IE, you can't directly construct the base class, only indirectly through the child class).

> ...if they're going to be used by the child class...

There's no way to *conditionally* enforce if a member should be overridden or not. If you apply `abstract`, it must be overridden in the child class.

There's also no way to opt-out of overriding an abstract member from the child class. A child class must override all abstract members from its base class.

> ...but if they're not overridden...

That's what [`virtual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual) is for. Virtual means that you *can* override a member in a child class, but if you don't then the base class's implementation holds.

> ...they can not be accessed by the child class...

Again, this doesn't make a lot of sense. You can mark a member as (as a simplified list) private or public (yes there are more). Private members can't be accessed by anyone but the base class, *including child classes*, but that also means you don't have the option for child classes to override them.

So you can't prevent a child class from accessing a base member that you're allowing it to override. `abstract` and `virtual` members cannot be `private`.

Answer (score -2):

by using the abstract keyword yes

information from Steve's comment

Comment: Please flesh out your answer (without referring to Steve's comment - which he could delete at any moment). You also need to explain what `abstract` will and won't do to answer the OP's question.

Comment: Also, don't just include Steve's link as your answer. Links should only be used as a supporting reference. Links get broken so the answer needs to be standalone.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).